# Show that $M$ is dense in $[0,1]$ $\Leftrightarrow$ if every interval $(a, b) \subset [0, 1]$ contains infinitely many elements of $M$.

Tags: general-topology

> $M$ is dense in $[0,1]$ $\Leftrightarrow$ every interval $(a, b) \subset [0, 1]$ contains infinitely many elements of $M$, for $M \subset [0,1]$

Density assumes, for $k \in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon > 0$,

$(k-\epsilon, k+ \epsilon) ∩ M \neq \emptyset.$

Can someone give me an indication on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** One direction is nearly trivial, you wrote most of the proof already when you wrote the definition of "dense".

In the other direction, show that if there is an interval $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b)\cap M$ is finite, then we can shrink it such that $(a,b)\cap M=\varnothing$, and therefore $M$ cannot be dense.

Comment: I think I get it, so the trivial direction is concluded by assuming there is indeed infinitely many elements of $M$, I can see how this is fairly trivial from the definition of denseness. For the other way by assuming $M$ is finite, an interval $(k - \epsilon , k+\epsilon) \subset M$ where $\epsilon$ would have to have a minimum value? As there must be a minimum distance between the points in $M$ - which goes against density hence a contradiction?

Comment: The other direction you suggest is awkward. We assume that $M\cap(a,b)$ is finite. Not that $M$ is finite and $(k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon)\subseteq M$. First deal with the case that $M\cap(a,b)$ has a single point, then two points, then figure out how this is generalized.